# C#- How to check whether given 2 strings with 2 or 3 words has single letter and compare first letter of 2 strings are same and return true or false?

Tags: c#, comparison

```
bool isMatch = false;

var string1list = string1.Trim().ToLower().Split(" ").ToList();
var string2list = string2.Trim().ToLower().Split(" ").ToList();
if (string1List.Count == string2List.Count)
{
    int tokenCount = string1List.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < tokenCount; i++)
    {
        if (string1List[i].Length == 1 || string2List[i].Length == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string1List[i][0] == string2List[i][0])
                {
                    isMatch = true;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    isMatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
return isMatch;
```

Example :

```
string string1 = "John M Marshal";
string string2 = "John M Marshal";
```

It has to first check whether the 2 strings have any single char word if yes it should go to comparison.

In comparison it should compare first letter of every word in both strings and if it is same it should return true or else false.

Comment: What have you tried, Priya? People are going to downvote on "just give me code" questions. You need to show your attempts / effort.

Comment: Please provide code sample of what you have already research and tried. We will not write the program for you...

Comment: What do you expect of names containing small letter words? Like "Piet van der Grachten" or "Richard von der Vogelweide"? What about Names containing more than one capital? "John McLeary"? What about "Sioban O'Connor"? What if middle name abbreviation is with a dot? "John M. Marshal"?

Comment: It can contain many letters also in case it should remove all the symbols and then compare

Comment: I have added the code which I have tried in this it is finiding whether it has one letter and comparing but it is not checking every word in the string.It is checking only the first word first letter and giving match is true.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RuXih9 <= Does this get near the desired behavior?

Comment: @Priya - Please never ever ever write `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` again. It's terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
string string1 = "John M Marshal";
string string2 = "John M Marshal";

string[] split1 = string1.Split(' ');
string[] split2 = string2.Split(' ');

bool result =
    split1.Any(x => x.Length == 1)
    && split2.Any(x => x.Length == 1)
    && split1.Length == split2.Length
    && split1.Zip(split2, (s1, s2) => s1[0] == s2[0]).All(x => x);
```

That gives me `true`.